# Slow scroll in infinite scroll flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement infinite scroll for my list which works perfectly fine , the only problem is that the scroll is kind of slow not smooth at all which I don't know why.
Is there a way with which I can make my scroll smoother  here's my list class:

```
class QrqcListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QrqcListViewState createState() => _QrqcListViewState();
}

late Future<QrqcDetails?> futureQrqc;
late ScrollController _controller;

List<Qrqc>? myList;
String? label;

int _count = 20;
int pageSize = 1;
bool isBottom = false;
bool isLoading = false;
bool _visible = true;

class _QrqcListViewState extends State<QrqcListView> {
  void _showToast(BuildContext context) {
    final scaffold = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
    scaffold.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: const Text('No more data to load'),
        action: SnackBarAction(
            label: 'UNDO', onPressed: scaffold.hideCurrentSnackBar),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<TypeSettings> listTypes = [];
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 8), () {
      //asynchronous delay
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _visible = false;
        });
      }
    });
    _controller = ScrollController();

    Provider.of<MyQrqcListViewModel>(context, listen: false).fetchMyQrqc();
    fetchTypes();

    super.initState();
  }

  fetchTypes() async {
    listTypes = (await SettingsViewModel().fetchTypes());
    setState(() {
      listTypes;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var myQrqcListViewModel = Provider.of<MyQrqcListViewModel>(context);

    myList = myQrqcListViewModel.articlesList;
    List<Qrqc>? qrqcList = myList;
    Future<List<Qrqc>>? _fetch(int count) {
      return Future.delayed(
        Duration(seconds: 1),
        () => qrqcList!.take(count).toList(),
      );
    }

    _controller.addListener(() {
      var triggerFetchMoreSize = 0.5 * _controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
      if (_controller.position.pixels ==
          (_controller.position.maxScrollExtent - 50)) {
        setState(() {
          isBottom = true;
        });

        if (qrqcList!.length == _count) {
          setState(() {
            _count += 20;
          });
        }
        print(_count);
      } else {
        setState(() {
          isBottom = false;
        });
      }
      print(isBottom);
    });

    QrqcDetails? result;
    String? type;

    String? setTypeLabel(int j) {
      for (int j = 0; j < qrqcList!.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listTypes.length; i++) {
          if (listTypes[i].id == qrqcList![j].typeID) {
            qrqcList[j].typeName = listTypes[i].label;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _fetch(_count),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            String? backgroundImage;
            return ScrollListener(
              threshold: 0.8,
              builder: (context, controller) {
                final listView = ListView.builder(
                    controller: _controller,
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: qrqcList!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      List<String>? typeNames;
                      String? typeName;

                      List<String>? _setTypeName() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < listTypes.length; i++) {
                          if (listTypes[i].id == qrqcList[index].typeID) {
                            typeNames!.add(listTypes[i].label);
                          }
                        }
                        return typeNames;
                        print(listTypes);
                      }

                      String? backgroundImage;

                      String? _setImage() {
                        setTypeLabel(index);
                        if (qrqcList![index].typeName == "Delivery") {
                          backgroundImage = "assets/icons/delivery.png";
                        } else if (qrqcList![index].typeName == "Security") {
                          backgroundImage = "assets/icons/security.png";
                        } else if (qrqcList![index].typeName == "Quality") {
                          backgroundImage = "assets/icons/quality.png";
                        } else if (qrqcList![index].typeName == "Cost") {
                          backgroundImage = "assets/icons/Cost.png";
                        } else if (qrqcList![index].typeName == "People") {
                          backgroundImage = "assets/icons/people.png";
                        } else {
                          backgroundImage = "assets/icons/unknown.png";
                        }

                        print("list types: $type");
                        print("_mTitle: $backgroundImage");
                        return backgroundImage; // here it returns your _backgroundImage value
                      }

                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          ConditionalBuilder(
                              condition: qrqcList[index].status == 'INIT',
                              builder: (context) => QrqcBody(
                                    child: QrqcCard(
                                        child: QrqcCardBody(
                                      color: Colors.orange,
                                      text: qrqcList[index].status,
                                      leading:
                                          QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath: _setImage()),
                                      trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(
                                        text:
                                            qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),
                                        percent:
                                            qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),
                                      ),
                                      title: qrqcList[index].id.toString(),
                                      subtitle: qrqcList[index].title,
                                      chlidren: [
                                        QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                                          product: "No product",
                                          role:
                                              qrqcList[index].role ?? "no role",
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                        QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                                          perim:
                                              qrqcList[index].perimeterName ??
                                                  "no perim",
                                          date: convertDateTimeDisplay(
                                              qrqcList[index].createdAt!),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                  ),
                              fallback: null),
                          ConditionalBuilder(
                              condition: qrqcList[index].status == 'SUBMITTED',
                              builder: (context) => QrqcBody(
                                    child: QrqcCard(
                                        child: QrqcCardBody(
                                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                      text: 'SUB',
                                      leading:
                                          QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath: _setImage()),
                                      trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(
                                        text:
                                            qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),
                                        percent:
                                            qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),
                                      ),
                                      title: qrqcList[index].id.toString(),
                                      subtitle: qrqcList[index].title,
                                      chlidren: [
                                        QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                                          product: "No product",
                                          role:
                                              qrqcList[index].role ?? "no role",
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                        QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                                          perim:
                                              qrqcList[index].perimeterName ??
                                                  "no perim",
                                          date: convertDateTimeDisplay(
                                              qrqcList[index].createdAt!),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                  ),
                              fallback: null),
                          ConditionalBuilder(
                              condition: qrqcList[index].status == 'VALIDATED',
                              builder: (context) => QrqcBody(
                                    child: QrqcCard(
                                        child: QrqcCardBody(
                                      color: Colors.green,
                                      text: 'Valid',
                                      leading:
                                          QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath: _setImage()),
                                      trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(
                                        text:
                                            qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),
                                        percent:
                                            qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),
                                      ),
                                      title: qrqcList[index].id.toString(),
                                      subtitle: qrqcList[index].title,
                                      chlidren: [
                                        QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                                          product: "No product",
                                          role:
                                              qrqcList[index].role ?? "no role",
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                        QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                                          perim:
                                              qrqcList[index].perimeterName ??
                                                  "no perim",
                                          date: convertDateTimeDisplay(
                                              qrqcList[index].createdAt!),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                  ),
                              fallback: null),
                          ConditionalBuilder(
                              condition: qrqcList[index].status == 'ESCALATED',
                              builder: (context) => QrqcBody(
                                    child: QrqcCard(
                                        child: QrqcCardBody(
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      text: 'ESCAL',
                                      leading:
                                          QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath: _setImage()),
                                      trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(
                                        text:
                                            qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),
                                        percent:
                                            qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),
                                      ),
                                      title: qrqcList[index].id.toString(),
                                      subtitle: qrqcList[index].title,
                                      chlidren: [
                                        QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                                          product: "No product",
                                          role:
                                              qrqcList[index].role ?? "no role",
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                        QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                                          perim:
                                              qrqcList[index].perimeterName ??
                                                  "no perim",
                                          date: convertDateTimeDisplay(
                                              qrqcList[index].createdAt!),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                  ),
                              fallback: null)
                        ],
                      );
                    });
                return Stack(
                  children: [
                    listView,
                    ConditionalBuilder(
                        condition: isBottom == true && _visible == true,
                        builder: (context) => Positioned(
                              left: 100,
                              right: 100,
                              bottom: 0,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 80,
                                height: 80,
                                child:
                                    Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                              ),
                            ),
                        fallback: null),
                  ],
                );
              },
              loadNext: () {
                if (qrqcList!.length == _count) {
                  setState(() {
                    _count += 20;
                  });
                }
                print(_count);
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return NoDataUI();
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        });
  }
}

String convertDateTimeDisplay(String date) {
  String createdAt = date.substring(1, 10);
  final DateFormat displayFormater = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  final DateFormat serverFormater = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
  final DateTime displayDate = displayFormater.parse(createdAt);
  final String formatted = serverFormater.format(displayDate);
  return formatted;
}

class ScrollListener extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, ScrollController) builder;
  final VoidCallback loadNext;
  final double threshold;
  ScrollListener({
    required this.threshold,
    required this.builder,
    required this.loadNext,
  });

  @override
  _ScrollListener createState() => _ScrollListener();
}

class _ScrollListener extends State<ScrollListener> {
  ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      final rate = _controller.offset / _controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
      if (widget.threshold <= rate) {
        widget.loadNext();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder(context, _controller);
  }
}
```

I was using two disposed methods , In my ListView class and the scroll listener class which gave me the following exception :

`a scrollcontroller was used after being disposed`

So I removed the disposed method that was in my ListView class , which I assume , resulted in a slow scroll , how can I fix this ? I'd be grateful for your your help

Answer (score 0):

It might be partly due to you running the app in the default `debug` mode. When active, Flutter compiles code as the app is running, causing it to slow down (for example when scrolling large/infinite lists). Its advantage are the hot reload capabilities while debugging.

Does running the app in profile mode prevent the issue from occuring? You can use `flutter run --profile` or use the `--profile` flag as an 'additional run arg' in your run configuration (Android Studio).

As an aside, I would suggest disposing the controller when the widget is destroyed

Comment: actually it has nothing to do with the debug mode , as the problem persists even when I run the app profile mode , but actually it has to do with a misplacement of initstate method

Comment: It could have played a part, I figured. Interesting that a mistake in `initState` could have such an effect, as it would normally only be run once (and should be fine after that). Was the issue that you had to call `super` before any of the other work?

Comment: Yes that , and also the fact that I used the listener on my controller outside the initstate function.